# Example of a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$x$\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

We know that the set of all ordered pairs of natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$x$\mathbb{N}$ is countable. A very good example of a bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$x$\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is $f(m,n) = 2^{m-1}(2n-1).$
I want a bijection in reverse direction $i.e$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$x$\mathbb{N},$  such that $\\$

$1 -> (1,1) \\$

$2 -> (1,2) \\$

$3 -> (2,1)\\$

$4 -> (3,1)$ etc.

Comment: Isn't this Cantor's diagonal argument?

Comment: The inverse of a bijection Is a bijection, just take the inverse of $f$

Comment: Just draw a bijection from N to the first infinite Von-Neumann ordinal; and draw a bijection from NxN to the first infinite von-Neumann ordinal. Invert and compose.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if $f:\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$ is a bijection, it's inverse gives a bijection in the opposite direction : $f^{-1}:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N^{2}$.

Using your function $f(m,n) = 2^{m-1}(2n-1)$, we can write :
$$f^{-1}(n) = \left(v_2(n)+1,\frac12\left(\frac{n}{2^{v_2(n)}}+1\right)\right)$$
with $v_2$ the $2$-adic valuation.

Another bijection is the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), given by :
$$g(n,m) = \frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}2+m$$
It's inverse is given [by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function) : $\newcommand{\w}{\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\newcommand{\t}{\frac{\w^2 +\w}2}$
$$g^{-1}(n) = \left(\w + \t-n,n-\t\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the inverse found by using 2-adic valuation a function with range in NxN, since we have v_2(1) = 0, hence for n = 1 the second co-ordinate becomes 0. Even for the second function we get 0 in the second co-ordinate for n = 1.

Comment: The second coordinate of $g^{-1}$ is negative for $n>1$.

Comment: @jjagmath True. I edited in the correct formula, which is much uglier.

Comment: @AtratranaSuna I made a sign error. It should be ok now

Comment: Thank you so much